# Unable to connect to PostgresSQL running on Docker

Tags: c#, postgresql, docker, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have the following PostgreSQL running on Docker, which I cannot connect to. When I try to connect using `Visual Studio 2022` extension `[Npgsql PostgreSQL Integration]`[1](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RojanskyS.NpgsqlPostgreSQLIntegration&ssr=false#overview), I get an error `Exception while connecting`. And when I try to connect using VS Code extension `[PostgreSQL by Chris Kolkman]`[2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ckolkman.vscode-postgres), I get an error `connect ETIMEDOUT 172.17.0.2:5432`. However, when I run C# REST API that connects to the same PostgreSQL using the same connection string, I am able to connect successfully. I wanted to change schema of some tables and I wanted to connect to database to run `ALTER TABLE` scripts:

**Docker**

```
C:\Users\HT>docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                           NAMES
4b22768d9f5e   postgres     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 days ago       Up 6 days       5432/tcp                                        gb-postgres
```

**Connection String**

```
Host=172.17.0.2;Database=GB3;Username=postgres;Password=Sila.1009
```

***Dockerfile***

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["GB3API/GB3API.csproj", "GB3API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "GB3API/GB3API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/GB3API"
RUN dotnet build "GB3API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "GB3API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "GB3API.dll"]
```

***Migration Fail***

```
PM> Add-Migration
cmdlet Add-Migration at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: PassColumnAddedInTestResult
Build started...
Build succeeded.
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2:5432
To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.
```

***How I am installing PostgreSQL***

```
Step 1 - Install Postgres

In the command line first
docker pull postgres

then 
docker run --name gb-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Sila.1009 -d postgres

Step 2 - Once Postgres is install you need to find out your instance IP address

In the command line first
docker ps

copy the {id  of the container} of the container and run

docker inspect {id  of the container}

copy the IPAddress of the container

Step 3 - Configure GB3 API

Open appSettings.json from the GB3 API

In dbConnectionString entry host should be the containers IP address

Step 4 - Run GB3 API container

if you are running the API from visual studio choose the docker profile and start debugging

if you are running the API out of VS:

from the command line go to the GB3 API folder, be sure you are at the same level of dockerfile, then

docker build --tag 'image_name'
docker run --detach 'image_name'
```

Comment: did you try with port in connection string? Host=172.17.0.2:5432.. also it will be good if you share the docker-compose

Comment: @KrishnaVarma, I am not using `docker-compose`, but only using `DockerFile`. I have edited question to add `DockerFile`

Comment: did you try Host=localhost:5432;Database=GB3;Username=postgres;Password=Sila.1009?

Comment: @KrishnaVarma, I tried the connection string from my API and it is connecting successfully. But outside of C# application, I am unable to connect. I have added How I am installing PostgreSQL in question.

Comment: try this.... docker run --name gb-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Sila.1009 -d postgres -p 5432:5432

Comment: @KrishnaVarma, when I ran `docker run --name gb-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Sila.1009 -d postgres -p 5432:5432`, I am getting this error `docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/gb-postgres" is already in use by container "4b22768d9f5e3d93106cee47f4e00250feab7511233fdcbe9cff77f383c3728c". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'docker run --help'.`

Comment: remove existing docker image.. docker stop 4b22768d9f5e   & then fire docker rm 4b22768d9f5e

Comment: @KrishnaVarma, I ran above commands and When I try to connect using `Visual Studio 2022` extension `Npgsql PostgreSQL Integration`, I get an error `Exception while connecting`.

Comment: @KrishnaVarma, when I run `Add-Migration`, even then I get an error `Error: Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2:5432
To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.`

Comment: @KrishnaVarma, now my C# application is giving error after I ran `docker run --name gb-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Sila.1009 -d postgres -p 5432:5432`, `Npgsql.NpgsqlException: 'Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2:5432' Timeout during connection attempt
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)`

Comment: try localhost:5432

Comment: There is more than one type authentication.  Many applications recently are transferring to OAUTH2 (instead of Windows) because OAUTH2 is supported with Linux, MAC, and Windows.  You docker may not be configurated for OAUTH2.  Read first paragraph carefully : https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/oauth/  Some applications try more than one type authentication after one method fails perform a second authentication using a different method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Host as `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` in connection string:

```
Host=localhost;Database=GB3;Username=postgres;Password=Sila.1009
```